# Clarify inner workings of the snapshot

Tags: iri-node, snapshot

We are in the middle of the January 2018 snapshot. Time to understand the inner workings.

First: The upcoming IRI update includes a [long list of addresses and balances](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/27aae832094f91276ebf41544f4f7cb5f14be0ab/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/Snapshot.java#L38).

However, strictly speaking there is no such *entity* as an *address* on the tangle. There are only *transactions*. The sum of all non-zero transactions pointing towards address A constitute its balance.

Now, a snapshot removes all zero-transactions from the tangle but doesn’t touch those with value. Is this correct?

If it is: Why do we need Snapshot.txt at all?

Second: How does IRI make use of Snapshot.txt? Does it use it to seed an (empty / new) database? Is reading it into memory and performing lookups?

Comment: Hunting down how all of this works, as far as I understand the IRI codebase, Snapshot.txt is read on every IRI start triggered by this line: https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/27aae832094f91276ebf41544f4f7cb5f14be0ab/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/Iota.java#L83. The question remains, how bundles based off of the initial milestone are built.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A snapshot removes **all** transactions from the tangle, and only keeps the balances. The balances at snapshot time (you can [verify them](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/pull/512) if you are running a  full node right now) are moved into `Snapshot.txt` instead. Also the minimum milestone number and minimum transaction time gets increased a bit (to avoid new nodes to see old transactions from before the snapshot).

When the new iri is released, the Coordinator will create a new milestone with the milestone number in `MILESTONE_START_INDEX` approving NULL_HASH (i. e. `999⋯9`) twice. This will be seen by iri as the initial milestone (compare to *genesis block* on a blockchain) and this milestone is considered by iri to have the balances that are in `Snapshot.txt`.

A new tangle will then grow from this transaction until it gets too big again, and the snapshot process repeats.